# using search and render component again

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to have a search box and after search, I request and get data from API and `setState`.
I send my request in `ComponentDidMount` and after search, `ComponentDidMount` do not call. If I use `componentDidupdate` I have for loop that never finished. what should I do?

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${this.state.searchString}`);
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({ movies: response.data });
    }catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

and :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      searchString: 'bing bang',
      boolian: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const searchString = navigation.getParam('searchString', 'searchString');
    if (this.state.boolian) {
      this.setState({ boolian: false, searchString });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate your api call to another method and call it on search

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      searchString: 'bing bang',
      boolian: true,
    };
}

showSearch = async (searchString) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${searchString}`);
      this.setState({ movies: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  this.showSearch(this.state.searchString)
}
```

and on Search Button press you can call as `this.showSearch(searchString)`